# Css wont link to HTML even though it worked before

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have one file in my folder and it works fine. When I copy paste it into a new file in the same folder, add some elements, it works. But when I make changes the file on the browser just stays the same. I changed the background to white and it didn't respond (the other file did!) Like I said, I copy pasted the link that WORKED so it can't be wrong... can it?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Hero Battle Arena.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Worlds Apart</title>
</head>
<body>
    //STUFF THAT ISN'T IMPORTANT
  <script src="Hero Battle Arena.js"></script>
<script src="Hero Battle Arena(game).js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200&display=swap');
  body {
    background: white;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: white;
  }
  button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background: #2f2e2e;
    border-radius: 10%;
    display: block;
    transition:0.25s;
  }
  button:hover{
    background: #565656;
  }
h1, p {
  font-family: 'Arvo',serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
li,ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four {
  display: none;
}
#readyBtn {
  display: inline-block;
}
#readyBtn:focus {
  background: black;
}
#hero-content {
  text-align:center;
  margin: auto;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#choseCha {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: purple;
}
```

If you would like, I could add some screenshots of the pages and how they look! Also,I'm using Sublime Text 3 and have all the links in the same folder. Have no idea why it wouldn't work.  I am using the latest version of Chrome, so it can't be anything with IE.

Comment: space is not allowed in file name. Change your href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the CSS file you linked. Spaces are not allowed for a filename.

Try changing the filename to one without space. that will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
body.bg-color{
  background:black;
}
    <html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Hero Battle Arena.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Worlds Apart</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-color">
    //STUFF THAT ISN'T IMPORTANT
  <script src="Hero Battle Arena.js"></script>
<script src="Hero Battle Arena(game).js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i added class to body tag and it solve your prblem.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. I will use that every time I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is working completely fine. Please do notice

```
body {
background: white;
box-sizing: inherit;
color: white;
}
```

has background and color set to white which in this case lays text(white) over background(white). Please do change the background to black or color as black.

Comment: I had it black. I changed it to white to see if the page was working, and it didn't.